# Javascript Regex restrict underscore at start and end

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a form where I want to restrict first and last characters. (javascript)
Restriction is:

- Input must start and end with alphanumeric, not underscore while just underscore is allowed in between alphanumeric.

Examples:

```
 Valid Entries: abc, ABC, Abc123, 123a, Abc_12, Abc_12_3a
 Invalid Entries: _abc, abc_, _abc_
```

I tried to create my regex as below:

```
^(?!\_)(?!_*_$)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

This does not allow underscore at the start which is fine but does allows underscore at the end which I want to restrict.

Any inputs whats missing here.

Thanks

---

```js
const validEntries = ['abc', 'ABC', 'Abc123', '123a', 'Abc_12', 'Abc_12_3a'];
const invalidEntries = ['_abc', 'abc_', '_abc_'];

const regex = /^(?!\_)(?!_*_$)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/;

validEntries.forEach((x) => {
  const ret = regex.test(x);
  
  console.log('Should be true :', ret);
});

console.log('-------------------');

invalidEntries.forEach((x) => {
  const ret = regex.test(x);
  
  console.log('Should be false :', ret);
});
```

---Updated---

I am using the regex in my angularjs application.

I have created my directive as:

```
       .directive('restrictField', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            var regReplace,
                preset = {                   
                    'alphanumeric-spl': '\\w_./\s/g',
                    'alphanumeric-underscore': '\\w_',
                    'numeric': '0-9',
                    'alpha-numeric': '\\w'
                },
                filter = preset[attrs.restrictField] || attrs.restrictField;                

            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                regReplace = new RegExp('[^' + filter + ']', 'ig');
                if (inputValue == undefined)
                    return ''
                cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(regReplace, '');
                if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
                    ctrl.$render();
                }
                return cleanInputValue;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

I am using this in my html as:

```
 <input type="text" name="uname" ng-model="uname" required class="form-control input-medium" restrict-field="alphanumeric-underscore" ng-trim="false" />
```

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: I think you're looking for `(?!.*_$)` not `(?!_*_$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry I dint mention, but consecutive underscores is also valid.

Comment: `^(?!_)(?!.*_$)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$` or `^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may add another negative lookahead (`(?!.*_$)`) and use

```
^(?!_)(?!.*_$)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H9F1NN/1). The `(?!.*_$)` lookahead will fail the match if after any 0+ chars other than line break chars there is a `_` at the end of the string.

Alternatively, you may use a lookaround-free pattern like

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
^[a-zA-Z0-9](\w*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H9F1NN/2). This pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alphanumeric char
- `([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` - 0 or more word chars (in JS, you may replace it with `\w*`)
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alphanumeric char
- `$` - end of string.

**Regarding the EDIT**

Your patterns are out of sync with the descriptions. Considering that `preset` should contain a pattern to use in the `replace` method, try the following keeping in mind that `\w` matches `_`:

```
'alphanumeric-spl': '[^\\w\\s./]+', // Removes all but alnum, _ . / whitespaces
'alphanumeric-underscore': '^_+|_+$|_+(?=_)|\\W+', // Removes all _ at start/end and all _ before a _ and all but alnum and _
'numeric': '[^0-9]+',  // Removes all but digits
'alpha-numeric': '[\\W_]+'  // Removes all but alnum
```

And then

```
regReplace = new RegExp(filter, 'ig');
```

Comment: while your regex works fine when I tried at online regex tester at: https://regex101.com/r/dX3hD4/1 but I cannot get it to work when I tried to integrate it with my code. I believe because I am using regex replace instead of test. I should have posted my actual code instead of just the regex. But now I have created a jsfiddle for the issue:  https://jsfiddle.net/d5ofunL8/1/ . Let me know how can I fix this. Sorry again for the repeated queries.

Comment: Would it be possible to adjust the code in according to what I have in my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d5ofunL8/8/. Its just that I am using a number of expressions here that I pass to the regexreplace function. And with the code you have updated you have removed the way I am calling it.

Comment: Would it be fine if I share my code here how I am using it as my previous code works (angularjs directive) ?

Comment: @kaka1234 Add all relevant code to the question please.

Comment: Wiktor, did you had time to review my post. Any inputs on that?

Comment: @kaka1234 You cannot use that approach (you need to remove text in different *contexts* while you are trying to remove any chars but those specified inside a negated character class), you will have to add more  programming logic or use other types of sanitizing input.

Comment: Wiktor, this is a input of type textbox. Is there any other options/workaround to restrict or use this kind of reqex on a textbox.

Comment: @kaka1234 Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. I suggested  a working approach in my answer.

Comment: Wiktor I will raise separate question for angularjs regex on textbox.