# RegEx: matching 20 letters with 1 optional dash

Tags: swift, regex

I'm struggling to write a regex that matches the following requirements:

1. up to 20 characters (English letters and numbers)
2. may have one optional dash ( - ) but can't start or end with it

I could come up with this patters: `^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,20}$` but this one allows for multiple dashes and one may enter the dash at the begin/end of the input string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314936/javascript-regex-restrict-underscore-at-start-and-end

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?=.{0,20}$)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KpWFYJ/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{0,20}$)` - zero to twenty chars allowed in the string
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group start:

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more alphanumeric chars
  - `(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?` -  an optional sequence of a `-` and one or more
    alphanumeric chars
- `)?` - end of the non-capturing group, repeat one or zero times (i.e. the pattern match is optional)
- `$`  - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
^(?:[^\W_]{1,20}|(?!.{22})[^\W_]+-[^\W_]+)$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CrxzkY/1)

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group;

  - `[^\W_]{1,20}` - Match between 1-20 alphanumeric characters;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `(?!.{22})[^\W_]+-[^\W_]+` - Negative lookahead to assert position is not followed by 22 characters, and next we matching 1+ alphanumeric characters between an hyphen;
- `)$` - Close non-capture group before matching end-line anchor.

Note that the above assumes upto 20 alphanumeric characters but with one optional hyphen that would take the max count to 21 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea by use of a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) at the end.

```
^(?!.{21})[A-Za-z\d]+-?[A-Za-z\d]*\b$
```

- `^(?!.{21})` the *lookahead* checks at start for max 20 characters
- `[A-Za-z\d]+` starting with [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) alphanumeric characters
- `-?[A-Za-z\d]*` [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) hyphen followed by any amount alnum
- `\b$` the *word boundary* forces to end with an alphanumeric char

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bUmfDO/1)

---

FYI: If `\pL` (*letter*) can be used to shorten: [`^(?!.{21})[\pL\d]+-?[\pL\d]*\b$`](https://regex101.com/r/20aQQJ/1)